# How do I render a <div> based on the screen size using a global variable in React JS without using a state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to render a  based on the screen resolution in React js. 
I am using function component and without using a state, by using a global variable, I need to achieve this.

```
const isDesktop = window.innerWidth;

{isDesktop > 768 ?  <div> Hi </div> : null}
```

Expected Result: Hi should render in desktop, tablet devices.

Comment: You should use media query for this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

Answer (score 0):

If you want "global values" you could consider to use context API

https://en.reactjs.org/docs/context.html

You can provide the window value in a context and get it from your components

```
const WindowWidthContext = React.createContext(0);
```

Then in your component:

```
<WindowWidthContext.Provider value={window.innerWidth}>
   // Every component inside can get the value via consumer
<WindowWidthContext.Provider/>
```